# How to Close Navigation Menu on Route Change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With `react-router-dom`, how can I detect when the user navigates to a new page?

I'm currently using `"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2"` and `"react": "^15.6.1"`. I want to close my mobile navigation menu when the user has selected a new target URL, but I'm having trouble detecting when the route has changed.

Is there a callback I can hook into for `react-router-dom`? I would like to be able to call code along the lines of `location.onChange(() => { this.state.collapsed = true; })`

*My current code is as follows:*

**Component:**

```
class Leftnav extends Component {

 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true,
    };
  }

  toggleMenu = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    })
  };

  render() { ... { */html here/* } ... };
};
```

**Template:**

```
<ul className={"leftnav-collapse " + (this.state.collapsed ? 'collapsed' : '')}>
    <li><NavLink to={`/events`} activeClassName="current">Events</NavLink></li>
    <li><NavLink to={`/people`} activeClassName="current">People</NavLink></li>
</ul>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This comes 4 years too late for the OP, however, I ended up here looking for a solution to the exact problem (albeit with newer versions of `react` and `react-router-dom`) so adding my solution here for others solving this problem.

When using functional components (which would be the recommended approach today), we can create a solution using `useLocation` (from `react-router-dom`) and `useEffect` (from `react`) hooks. A component like the following would close the menu on navigation.

```
function LeftNav() {
  const [isOpen, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const {pathname} = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setOpen(false); // Close the navigation panel
  }, [ pathname ]);
  
  return ( /* your jsx */ );
}
```

**A short explanation:** In the above component, we obtain the location object from `useLocation` hook and extract current `pathname` from there. The value of pathname is going to be updated on user navigation. The `useLocation` hook also takes care of re-rendering your component (due to state update within hook) whenever that happens. All we need to do after that is create an useEffect hook that closes the menu when pathname changes.

This pattern can be used to take any action in a component based on client side navigation.

Answer (score 5):

```
<NavLink to={`/events`} 
         activeClassName="current"
         onClick={this.toggleMenu}
    >Events</NavLink>
```

You may need to also update the `toggleMenu` function to prevent the default click action, now that a click handler is applied.

```
toggleMenu = (e) => {
    if (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed});
}
```

Comment: Thanks gravityplanx. How could I adjust your example to work with the following situations? a.) If I click on the link to my current page, no URL change happens, so I want the menu to stay open and b.) If I click a link elsewhere on the page, my URL changes, so I would like the nav menu to close.

Comment: a) Use a combination of react-router's [`activeStyle`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md#activestyle-object) attribute along with the css property [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. The menu is being closed on link click, not on route change.

This may be irrelevant if the side bar is the only thing triggering a navigation in the app, but if the navigation is triggered by other factors (eg: timeout, server response), this will not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking for a solution for `functional component` and `nextjs` follow this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const [MobileMenu, setMobileMenu] = useState(false);
const { pathname } = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
        setMobileMenu(false); // close menu if path changes!
    }, [ pathname ]);

<div onClick={()=>setMobileMenu(!MobileMenu)}>
     <i className="las la-bars"></i>
</div>
```

That's it!