# using Link instead of <a href>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have some issues in my ReactJS project. I was using a hamburger menu in my site's corner and I was using  to point to the other pages. The issue is that I had to change from   `<li><a href="/LoginPage">Login Page</a></li>`   to   `<li><Link to="/LoginPage">Login Page</Link></li>` and then my Hamburger tab does not close itself after I press on some certain page. I was using state and some javascript code for it. Now since it didn't work I tried some changes in my JSX file: `<Link to={{pathname: "/LoginPage", state: closeSideDrawer}}>Login Page</Link>` and I had this code as well

```
render() {
        this.state = {
            user: null,
            sideDrawerOpen: false
        };
        let closeSideDrawer = () => {
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                return {sideDrawerOpen: prevState.sideDrawerOpen};
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: You never declare or manipulate state in `render()`

Comment: Please, provide more code so we can reproduce the issue. That is this Link component, from where is it?

Comment: He's probably talking about Link from react-router https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Close Navigation Menu on Route Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46244279/how-to-close-navigation-menu-on-route-change)